# escaping image_tag in rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, escaping

In my view I have:

```
= image_tag i.object.image(:big)
```

This makes my browser render the image,

I would like instead my browser to show the HTML tag, I need this to  get the image tag ready ready to be copy pasted somewhere else.

I've tried with:

```
= h image_tag i.object.image(:big)
```

but the image is rendered as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this `= "#{image_tag i.object.image(:big)}"`